# What is {pushId} in this Firebase function for sending notification

Tags: node.js, firebase, google-cloud-functions

I am trying to create a firebase function to send notification to specific device or user. But I am just confused that what {pushId} that we are passing in ref. Is it user Id or device registration code? Any guidance would be appreciated.

```
/* Listens for new messages added to /messages/:pushId and sends a        notification to subscribed users */
 exports.pushNotification = functions.database.ref('/messages/{pushId}').onWrite( event => {
console.log('Push notification event triggered');
/* Grab the current value of what was written to the Realtime Database */
var valueObject = event.data.val();
/* Create a notification and data payload. They contain the notification information, and message to be sent respectively */ 
const payload = {
    notification: {
        title: 'App Name',
        body: "New message",
        sound: "default"
    },
    data: {
        title: valueObject.title,
        message: valueObject.message
    }
};
/* Create an options object that contains the time to live for the notification and the priority. */
const options = {
    priority: "high",
    timeToLive: 60 * 60 * 24 //24 hours
};
return admin.messaging().sendToTopic("notifications", payload, options);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

When defining a Realtime Database trigger, you can can specify a wildcard in the reference path with `{wildcard}`.  This will match any component in the path that would trigger this function.

From the [documentation about database triggers](https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/database-events):

> You can specify a path component as a wildcard by surrounding it with
>   curly brackets; `ref('foo/{bar}')` matches any child of `/foo`. The values
>   of these wildcard path components are available within the
>   `EventContext.params` object of your function. In this example, the
>   value is available as `event.params.bar`.

Comment: okay so you mean if I have ref to users and then each pushId would be each id under user?